# Manual workflow triggers in Github Actions

Tags: docker, kubernetes, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am setting up Github Actions for a project repository.

The workflow consists of the following steps:

- Building a docker image
- Pushing the image to a container registry
- Rollout a Kubernetes deployment.

---

However, I have two different Kubernetes deployments: one for development, and one for production. Hence, I have also two Github Action workflows.

The Github Action workflow for development is triggered everytime that a commit is pushed:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
```

But I don't want that for my production workflow. I would need a manual trigger, like a *Send to production* button. I didn't see anything close to that in the docs.

---

***Is there a way to trigger a workflow manually in Github Actions?***

***How can I split my development and my production workflows to achieve what I want, either on Github Actions, Docker or Kubernetes?***

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> Is there a way to trigger a workflow manually in Github Actions?

You might consider, [from July2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-07-06-github-actions-manual-triggers-with-workflow_dispatch/):

> ### GitHub Actions: Manual triggers with workflow_dispatch

(Note: or multiple workflows, through the [new Composite Run Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317065/6309), August 2020)

> You can now create workflows that are manually triggered with the new `workflow_dispatch` event.
> You will then see a '`Run workflow`' button on the Actions tab, enabling you to easily trigger a run.
>
> [image: https://i2.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/1865328/86147571-2de93700-babf-11ea-8a08-e4beffd3abe9.png?ssl=1]
>
> You can choose which branch the workflow is run on.

[philippe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631219/philippe) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933155/manual-workflow-triggers-in-github-actions/62768214#comment111440150_62768214):

> One thing that's not mentioned in the documentation: the workflow must exist on the default branch for the "`Run workflow`" button to appear.
> Once you add it there, you can continue developing the action on its own branch and the changes will take effect when run using the button

The documentation goes on:

> In addition, you can optionally specify inputs, which GitHub will present as form elements in the UI. Workflow dispatch inputs are specified with the same format as action inputs.
>
> For example:

```
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'     
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
```

> The triggered workflow receives the inputs in the `github.event` context.
>
> For example:

```
jobs:
  printInputs:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: |
        echo "Log level: ${{ github.event.inputs.logLevel }}"
        echo "Tags: ${{ github.event.inputs.tags }}"
```

---

[shim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032372/shim) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58933155/manual-workflow-triggers-in-github-actions/62768214?noredirect=1#comment121548076_62768214):

> You can add `workflow_dispatch` to a workflow that also has other triggers (like `on push` and / or `schedule`)
>
> [For instance](https://gist.github.com/simonbromberg/d9dfbbd3fcf481dd59dc522f0d12cdf6):
>
> ```yaml
> on:
>  workflow_dispatch:
>  push:
>    branches:
>      - master
>  pull_request:
>    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened]
> ```

Comment: One thing that's not mentioned in the documentation: the workflow must exist on the default branch for the "Run workflow" button to appear. Once you add it there, you can continue developing the action on its own branch and the changes will take effect when run using the button.

Comment: @philippe Thank you for that feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Can this be used with collaborator or maintainer permissions only?

Comment: @A.Wentzel I believe collaborator or above but I haven't tested it. Related: https://github.community/t/who-has-permission-to-workflow-dispatch/133981/3

Comment: Can you add  `workflow_dispatch` to a workflow that also has other triggers (like on push and / or schedule)? Can't quite figure out the syntax

Comment: @shim Not sure. That could be a good question on its own.

Comment: Just realized I was just missing a colon, even though it looks kind of weird. [Here's an example in a gist](https://gist.github.com/simonbromberg/d9dfbbd3fcf481dd59dc522f0d12cdf6)

Comment: @shim Well done. I have included your comment and example in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to filter only a specific branch in the branch selection of the workflow_dispatch form?

Comment: @HugoLeonardo Bot sure: you could ask a separate question, with a clear illustration of "filter only a specific branch in the branch selection of the workflow_dispatch form", for us to asnwer.

Answer (score 23):

**EDITED** :

Great tweet explaining the use of workflow dispatch :
https://twitter.com/github/status/1321859709075394563?s=19

---

> Is there a way to trigger a workflow manually in Github Actions?

I've got a little hack to do so...

With the watch event, you can manually trigger an action by star or unstar the repo. The code for the event in your workflow is :

```yaml
on:
  watch
    types: [started]
```

I know it's weird but it works! Nevertheless, it's not the best way if it's a public repo with potential stars.

---

> How can I split my development and my production workflows to achieve what I want, either on Github Actions, Docker or Kubernetes?

In Github Actions I mean, you can do multiple workflows / jobs and filter by targeted branches or events. You can combine multiple events for example trigger a workflow for **push and with a cron** on midnight.

Comment: Haha, this is great :> `repository_dispatch` aside, one can combine `watch` with `if: github.actor == 'hackerman'` to filter out random strangers. Or better yet - `if: github.actor == github.event.repository.owner.login` for extra "security" :D

Comment: Haha thanks! Yes good idea, I've to try this out when I got time ! :D

Comment: Perfect I think this is the best method while there isn't something officially implemented.

Answer (score 9):

**Update**: For a slash command style "ChatOps" solution see [slash-command-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) action. This can allow you to trigger workflows with slash commands (e.g. `/deploy`) from issue and pull request comments.

Here is a basic example for a `deploy` slash command. `REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN` is a `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

```
name: Slash Command Dispatch
on:
  issue_comment:
    types: [created]
jobs:
  slashCommandDispatch:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Slash Command Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          commands: deploy
```

The command can be processed in this workflow.

```
name: Deploy Command
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [deploy-command]
```

There are many more options and different setups. See [slash-command-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) for full usage instructions.

**Original Answer**:
A `repository_dispatch` workflow can be manually triggered by a call to the GitHub API as follows.

```
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [production-deploy]
```

- `[username]` is a GitHub username
- `[token]` is a `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)
- `[repository]` is the name of the repository the workflow resides in.

```
curl -XPOST -u "[username]:[token]" \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.everest-preview+json" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/[username]/[repository]/dispatches \
  --data '{"event_type": "production-deploy"}'
```

Comment: For anyone interested, it's possible to use single workflow for multiple dispatches. What's sent as `event_type` is available to workflow as `github.event.action`, so specific jobs/steps can be enabled/disabled when needed.
PS: PAT is not really needed, starting curl with `-u "[username]:[password]"` or even `-u "[username]"` works as well (in second case curl prompts user for password); easier to use in some cases (for example when writing scripts which takes username as input, or scripts intended to be used by less tech-savvy users).

Answer (score 6):

Another way to resolve this with the current Github Action offering is to create a `production` branch from master when a deploy is needed & trigger deploy action on the `production` branch. The `production` branch is essentially a mirror of the `master`.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - master
```

Dev builds/push can happen whenever there is a commit to the master.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - production
```

At some point in the release schedule, you can raise the PR to the `production` branch. This will take care of the prod build/deploy.

Answer (score 5):

Although [Sarah's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58965362/3250340) was the closest and simplest answer to the original question, it is somewhat hacky so we eventually ended up by creating a `dev` branch to use the following triggers:

- Development workflow: triggered when a push is made on the `dev` branch:

  ```
  on:
    push:
      branches:    
        - dev
  ```
- Production workflow: triggered when a pull request / merge is made from `dev` to `master`:

  ```
  on:
    pull_request:
      branches:    
        - master
  ```

Answer (score 5):

**Edited for more detail/explanation.**

One thing that you can do is call to `repository_dispatch`. You can view the GitHub documentation for using a `repository_dispatch` [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#external-events-repository_dispatch).

For example, if you have a GitHub Actions workflow that looks like this:

```
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types: [run_tests]
name: Run tests
jobs:
  test:
    name: Run your tests
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: |
          echo "I just ran all your tests!"
```

You can create a repository dispatch event by following the steps that are explained on the [GitHub v3 API Documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-dispatch-event).

First, [create a personal access token (PAT)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line#creating-a-token) on GitHub for authentication.

Then, you can run `curl` like so:

```
curl \
  -H "Authorization: token $YOUR_PAT" \
  --request POST \
  --data '{"event_type": "run_tests"}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/$USER/$REPOSITORY/dispatches
```

At the same time, I also wanted to share a small project that I've been working on with a buddy that solves this exact problem.

https://www.actionspanel.app/

ActionsPanel uses this same `repository_dispatch` API but does so with a GitHub App token so that you don't need to worry about managing your own PAT. This also makes it much easier to trigger your actions across teams with multiple people.

Based on user requests and feedback, we've built in features to specify which branch to send the `repository_dispatch` to, and we've even built in a way to inject parameters when you want to execute the action.

You configure your buttons with a declarative yaml file that you leave in the repo, and ActionsPanel will read that file and dynamically create your UI for you to trigger your actions.

Answer (score 3):

What GitHub cryptic documentation fails to clarify is that you can have multiple workflow files under `.github/workflows`, each with its own trigger. For instance, I've a workflow that builds and runs tests on every push and pull request, and another that is triggered manually to publish the artifact.

```
(ci.yml)

name: CI Pipeline
on: [push, pull_request]

---
(publish.yml)

name: Publish
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
```