# How to create outputs on GitHub actions from bash scripts?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action that essentially is a bash script. The javascript portion of my action executes a bash script:

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
const exec = require("@actions/exec");

async function run() {
  try {
    // Execute bash script
    await exec.exec(`${__dirname}/my-action-script.sh`);
  } catch (error) {
    core.setFailed(error.message);
  }
}

run();
```

For now, this action will communicate with other actions by leaving files on the file system. This is an "invisible" way of communication and I would like to fill my `action.yml` with outputs. How can I enable `my-action-script.sh` to return me outputs defined in my `action.yml`?

Comment: Note: see also (loosely related) https://stackoverflow.com/a/63317065/6309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the output must first be added to the `action.yml`, ex:

```
name: some GitHub workflow yaml file
description: some workflow description
runs:
  using: node12
  main: dist/index.js
inputs:
  some_input:
    description: some input
    required: false
outputs:
  some_output:
    description: some output
```

and create the output from the bash script, ex:

```
echo ::set-output name=some_output::"$SOME_OUTPUT"
```

then you can use it in your workflow yaml, ex:

```
${{ steps.<step id>.outputs.some_output }}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense as you give an example of an `action.yml` using _javascript_, but then go on to talk about output from a _bash_ script

Comment: I think the answer makes perfect sense... the action is using javascript and the sole purpose of the javascript is to execute a bash script..

Answer (score 0):

Not totally clear if this is an action in a repo, or something you want to publish to the marketplace. At any rate, creating the output is done in the same way as indicated by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62320615/891440), although you can run directly the shell if you use:

```yaml
name: some GitHub workflow yaml file
description: some workflow description
runs:
  using: composite
  main: my-action-script.sh
inputs:
  some_input:
    description: some input
    required: false
outputs:
  some_output:
    description: some output
```

See [this article on creating this kind of actions](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-run-steps-action)

Comment: This doesn't make sense as there's no "runs.main" for composite actions

Comment: @DanForever I bet this is conflating various pipeline tools and their directives.  Possibly Azure?