# Github action update re run for a tag

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this github action that I think is wrong and didn't run for tags.

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    - /^v[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$/
```

I think that should be:

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    tags:
    - v.*
```

My question is, after I update this ci config, how can I re-run this CI so that it runs on the tags? Or should I create a new tag just because I want this CI to run on it (I think this sounds bad since it means I created another release/tag without any actual updates, only CI config)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since July 2020, you could [add a `workflow_dispatch` event and trigger manually your GitHub ACtion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62768214/6309)
(the workflow must exist on the default branch for the "`Run workflow`" button to appear)

That way, you can try and see if it does run based on your new `tag` criteria.